# What is the exact meaning of "This heart stays cloaked" on "Cloaked" by Woolf and the Wondershow?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

I recently found this interesting indie song on Spotify called *Cloaked* by Woolf and the Wondershow and I’m kinda confused on some lyrics, to be precise on "This heart stays cloaked".

What does "cloak" mean on "heart"? Is it someone’s heart being hurt and hidden away by putting some cloak?

[The song on Spotify](https://open.spotify.com/album/5CUCvkwTRThKTb8XFWHAwp) (or [on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57WvGQWYAdY)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, yes, pretty much. Cloaking your heart would be like masking the pain. Imagine being hurt on the inside, and having to put on a fake smile to 'cloak' it. The actual 'cloak' is metaphorical. That's what cloaking your heart means.

Answer (score 1):

"[...] hidden away by putting some cloak?"

You pretty much got it. The song is about how he used to be open to love, but now he guards himself from it. His heart stays hidden.